# Why Rotating Elements With CSS Produces Aliasing?

Tags: css, html

I was testing rotation on div. I noticed that when i rotate div with CSS, it produces aliasing  which looks awkward. Here is the Fiddle:

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/8Hr7u/1/)

**CSS:**

```
.alaised {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px solid green;
    transform:rotate(-8deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-8deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-8deg);
    margin:50px;
}
```

In the fiddle, when div is rotated it is aliased and on hover when not rotated, anti-aliased.

How can I remove this behaviour? I tried searching on web and tried by adding shadows of small width with same color but shadow of it is also aliased.

Note: This Behaviour is not detected on higher resolution screens. But on 1024x768 and less which are the most common resolutions these days suffer from this.

Answer (score 0):

just found an approach: http://jsfiddle.net/zGAvZ/1/ (tried on fx 18)

relevant CSS

```
.aliased {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
}

.aliased:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border:2px solid green;
    transform:rotate(-8deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-8deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-8deg);
}

.aliased:hover {
    transform:rotate(8deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(8deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(8deg);    
}
```

The idea is to rotate the `:after` pseudoelement on normal state and make an opposite rotation on the element itself on hover. On Firefox 18 the square looks nice even after the hover state

Comment: no, I see a different result: in your example I clearly see serrated edges after the hover for just a while, and in my example the edges are always smooth

Comment: what about chrome, opera, safari and IE? Wait a min, i check it on FF18. And What is the Resolution of your screen?

Comment: In chrome the effect is nice. Opera and IE are not supported in your example, so I didn't tried. Why the resolution should matter? :|

Comment: @FabrizioCaldren when website is on higher resolution, the pixels supporting the area are abundant and sharped by VGA cards. But on the Resolution like 1024x768, it is visible clearly. I tested on 1366x768 and 1024x768. On 1366x768, there was no alaising. But 1024x768 has.